# no script tag in firefox

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, browser, cross-browser

IS `<noscript>` tag supported in Firefox 3.5+ ? I used this for an alert message and used IE while coding this , but after setting all proper css i dont get anything on forefox when js is disabled
  EG: `<noscript>JS disabled</noscript>`
is fine on IE but not on FF.

Comment: What does the Firefox documentation say? Have you checked?

Comment: It does support only in my app i am not getting it , its working fine for stackoverflow site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IN ie i had included in  section FF didnt recognize this , so i put it in body now its fine .